# Why is it "девяностОлетний", but "сорокАлетний"?

Tags: морфология

Why is it "девяностОлетний", but "сорокАлетний"?

Isn't it like the linking vowels in Russian are only "о" and "е"?

Comment: And двадцатилетний.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These are the rules for declining composits with the first numeral root. 
We use the genitive in this case but not a connecting vowel:

Одиннадцать → одиннадцат**и**

Двадцать → двадцат**и**

Тридцать → тридцат**и**

Сорок → сорок**а**

Пятьдесят → пятидесят**и**

Шестьдесят → шестидесят**и**

Семьдесят → семидесят**и**

Восемьдесят → восьмидесят**и**

Еxceptions: *один (одн**о**летний), девяносто (девяност**о**летний), сто (ст**о**летний), тысяча (тысяч**е**летний)*. In these cases we use connecting vowels.

Sourse: Розенталь, «Справочник по правописанию и литературной правке» (М. , 1978), 37 page, 6 point.

Comment: The second one.

Comment: What about «миллионолетие», «сороконожка», are they  also exceptions?

Comment: §37 РозентальЧислительное сорок входит в состав сложных слов в двух формах — без соединительной гласной: сорокалетие, сорокадневный и с соединительной гласной: сорокоуст, сороконожка (в этом случае не в прямом значении счета).

Comment: The English version: There are two forms with 40,  when you count something you use сорока (see the examples above), the other usage is not direct counting, so there's a connecting -о.(сороконожка)

Comment: In other words it's just should be memorized - I mean when a rule have this much of exceptions.

Comment: This answer only re-states the facts already mentioned in the question. I'd really like to see an answer that addresses the *why*. And I hope it won't be just "because Rosenthal said so." :)